# How to prove the equivalence between sets?

Tags: functions

I want to prove that if $A$ is equivalent to $C$ and $B$ equivalent to $D$ then $A\times B$ is equivalent to $C\times D$. 
I used $f(a,b)= (h(a),g(b))$ where $h: A \rightarrow C$ one-to-one correspondence and $g: B \rightarrow D$ also one to one correspondence

I will be very thankful if any one help me

Comment: Define equivalent.

Comment: You are on the right track. On base of bijectivity of $h$ and $g$ it must be shown that $f$ is bijective. What withholds you from doing so?

Comment: Can I say : f(m,n) = f(o,p) for some m,n,o and p in AxB then (m,n)=(o,p) as h and g are one-to-one?